# Post OData service fine in Postman, but fail by web api program

Tags: asp.net-web-api, odata

I have create a OData service to insert database:

OData controller:

```
    public class ReportParameterController : ODataController
    {
    private ReportChatBotModel db = new ReportChatBotModel();

    [HttpPost]
    [ODataRoute("PostReportParameter")]
    public IHttpActionResult Post(ReportParameterData data)
    {

        var reportParameter = new ReportParameter { Year = data.Year, IsLatest = true };
        switch (data.Period)
        {
            case "Quarter One":
                reportParameter.Quarter = "1";
                break;
            case "Quarter Two":
                reportParameter.Quarter = "2";
                break;
            case "Quarter Three":
                reportParameter.Quarter = "3";
                break;
            case "Quarter Four":
                reportParameter.Quarter = "4";
                break;
            default:
                return BadRequest();
        }

        db.ReportParameters.Add(reportParameter);
        db.SaveChanges();

        return Ok();
    }
```

And I write a web api to call above service, using http client:

```
 using (var client = new HttpClient())
                {
                    var values = new ReportParameterData { Year = year, Period = period };

                    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://myTestHost:44307/ChatBot.Services");

                    var responseString = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("odata/PostReportParameter", values)
                        .ContinueWith((postTask) => postTask.Result.EnsureSuccessStatusCode());
                }
```

I used Postman to call the OData service, it works fine, but when I try to use web api to consume the OData service, the error message was 404 Not Found.Any advise to figure out what is root the cause? Many thanks!!

Comment: did you try looking looking with fiddler. See what the request url and payload looklike. Also you should try putting the full url in client.PostAsJsonAsync.

Comment: Thanks for reminder, after I put the full url in post method the problem solved.